# how to check if a sqlite field is available in django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

i want to make something like this, `select tipe from table_name where username == user.username`
im using sqlite, what i have already tried is using this method `Entry.objects.get(headline__exact="Cat bites dog")` that i got from the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/), but i cant find where to put the `column` that i want to print, because i only want to check one column, and if that column field is equal to `teacher` then i want to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a model named People with a column named occupation:

`People.objects.get(occupation="teacher")` should return you a queryset object containing all the teachers you have in your database.

If you want to print anything you just have to make a for loop going through each object in the queryset.

On the other hand if you want a single with only the fields you select list try using:
`People.objects.values_list('occupation', flat=True)`

Comment: does this method print the whole row ?, i only want tho check if a `value` in one `field` is equal to `teacher`, based on the username that is logged in right now

Comment: The method itself doesn't print anything. The case depends on what you want to do with the value. If you want to do a permission checking based on the value of the field then you should extend the user model, however, if you want to do something else with it you could just get the model instance and get one of its values like:
 `person = People.objects.get(name="some_name")
print(person.occupation)`